# what is the best way to use mixins in redux with es6 standard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mixins

I am just a new kid learning React/Redux which is pretty cool.But some functions are not supported by es6 standard.Yes i saw many alternative ways But I am not able to get it (Using high order functions).Any help to add mixins to my React es6 code

```
 import React from 'react';
    import Fetch from 'whatwg-fetch';
    import jwt from 'jwt-simple';
    import Reflux from 'reflux';

    const secret = 'goal';

    class Form extends React.Component{
        // mixins:[
        //     Not supported in es6
        //  ],
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               value:'',
               posted:''
           }
       }

        onPost(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(this.refs.email.value && this.refs.name.value != ''){
                const data = {
                    email:this.refs.email.value,
                    name:this.refs.name.value
                };
                const encodehead = jwt.encode(data,secret);
                const encrypt = {
                    encode:encodehead
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/post',
                    headers: {
                        kovam: encodehead

                    },

                })

            }
        }
        render(){
       console.log(this.state);
            return (
                <div>
                    <form className="postform" onSubmit={this.onPost.bind(this)}>
                        <label>Email Addres</label>
                        <input type="email" ref="email" className="form-control"/>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" ref="name" className="form-control"/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Post To server</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Higher Order Components](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) instead, mixins are no longer used in ES6 classes, see [this article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.91cnjakws).

Comment: Can you pls write an example for this code with high order functions

Comment: try it out yourself and post it - that's how you learn. I can check it then.

Comment: Ok I will try it @leo

Comment: Bro I can't get it pls Post that snippet

Comment: Here's [a blog post from Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.oegiitgv9) and [a gist from Sebastian Markbåge](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) about higher order components

Comment: haha that's exactly what I've linked, funny how we thought about the same resources

Answer (score 0):

Use the ES6 API from Reflux: https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs#react-es6-usage

It's currently only available from that git repo itself (not npm or anything yet), but it works well.